# only delete or only update or update+delete mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Usual task - user registration.
But what about user and their personal data deletion?

Should I just delete rows (from all related tables) or just update column "deleted" for instance, and then always use additional "where deleted=false" clause?

Please, base your answer in terms of speed, optimization if possible.

P.S. I don't need to keep this data. And what if always "update" and e.g. once a week "delete all updated" rows is better solution than always update?

Answer (score 0):

You have not expressed whether you have a reason to keep info about deleted users or not.  If you need to keep it, the answer is obvious; if you don't, then delete it (unneeded rows complicate & slow down queries, besides using more space than needed).

Answer (score 0):

**Delete**

- Your database has less redundant data
- Your queries are cleaner
- Related data may need to be removed

**Flags**

- You keep an audit of users
- Related data can be left in place
- Your queries are littered with `WHERE userId = 123`

Notice I didn't list any as *pro* or *con*. That's down to you to decide.

Answer (score 0):

I think you answered your own question. I don't know if this database is for personal use or not but in my opinion is to always keep unwanted data for a period of time. I would recommend setting a flag to a numeric value such as 1 and have a weekly job that deletes all these records from the appropriate tables.